# How to check if the process ended and then execute the next command in C# ProcessStartInfo?

Tags: c#, process.start, processstartinfo

I have a piece of code that runs command line and do some stuff as beneath:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
        System.Console.WriteLine("please insert the path of working directory");
        string path = System.Console.ReadLine();
        psi.WorkingDirectory = path; //@"D:\Exercises\npp52\scintilla\src";
        psi.Arguments = "/C dir /s /b | cccc - --outdir=d:\\jon";
        psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        Process.Start(psi);
        // ... cut ...
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\jon\anonymous.xml");
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType) { /* ... */ }
        }
```

The second piece does not wait until first piece is finished and then start. Particularly before first piece will produce anonimous.xml second piece is trying to take that xml.

Answer (score 3):

If you add this line:

```
Process.Start(psi);
psi.WaitForExit(); // <-- add this
```

Your code should wait for the process to end.